# SugarCrm API timeouts

Tags: c#, php, api, sugarcrm, suitecrm

We are troubled by a server that bogs down after a while, and I have no clue in what direction I should be troubleshooting anymore. Hence I am looking for a technical answer to nudge me into the right direction. There are these clues that I find quiete specific, but I don't know what to do with them. Maybe you do. Let me clarify the situation below.

There is this piece of software that communicates with SugarCRM (or factually SuiteCrm 7.3.2) through the SOAP API. Written in using C#.Net, which takes the WSDL and creates a strong typed client. Now all is functioning, data is fetched and can be stored. But after a while, the server seems to bog down. I haven't figured out what is causing the problem. Though I have one specific question, but first, let me state some specifics I gathered while throubleshooting the problem. Let me remind you that this only happens after a while, after a fresh server (re)start, all is functioning well and fast.

When the problem occurs:

1. The server seems to time out when a 'set_entries' function is called. The data given to this API function is persisted, but the server doens't answer the call, hence the client thinks it times out.
2. It seems API session related. Because when it happens with API session id 'X', no data can be stored or fetched anymore using this session, though the session is qualified as valid by the server when asked. But as soon as a new session 'Y' is created, data can be fetched again. But as soon as data is stored with session 'Y', the problem occurs again, and session 'Y' seems to have become unusable as well.
3. A server restart clears all issues.
4. No PHP errors in the log seem to be related.
5. Sugarcrm log isn't usefulll either, not with 'info' level set. It persists the given data, but simply doesn't return an answer.

**Now the specific question: How can this be API session id related?** How can it be that it seems to work again with a new session id (a bit slower than after a fresh server restart), even though the session is still valid (says the API, and the session is less than 15 secs old).

I am looking for a technical answer that can point in the right direction.